# json NewDecoder Decode not parsing integers

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to make an API endpoint which would save stuff into a database however, the integers which I pass in via POST request don't seem to be parsing correctly

Here's my structs:

```
type OnlineTestForm struct {
  Form  OnlineTestSet   `json:"form"`
}
type OnlineTestSet struct {
  ID                   int      `db:"id"                     json:"id"`
  OnlineTestSubjectId  int      `db:"online_test_subject_id" json:"online_test_subject_id"`
  Name                 string   `db:"name"                   json:"name"`
  ScoreToPass          int      `db:"score_to_pass"          json:"score_to_pass"`
  TimeLimit            int      `db:"time_limit"             json:"time_limit"`
  Description          string   `db:"description"            json:"description"`
  Enabled              bool     `db:"enabled"                json:"enabled"`
  Online               bool     `db:"online"                 json:"online"`
  TestType             string   `db:"test_type"              json:"test_type"`
  DocName              string   `db:"doc_name"               json:"doc_name"`
}
```

And the "problematic" function where I parse the JSON into a struct:

```
func NewOnlineTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
  var jsonForm OnlineTestForm
  json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&jsonForm)
  err := addNewOnlineTest(jsonForm.Form)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    w.WriteHeader(500)
    fmt.Fprint(w, "{\"error\": {\"message\": \"An error occured while adding new test - "+err.Error()+"\"}}")
    return
  }

  w.WriteHeader(200)
}
```

I'm using [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) for as my router and the route to which I post is defined like this

```
router.POST("/onlinetest/new", NewOnlineTest)
```

And finally the test POST request which I send has the following payload:

```
{
  "form":{
    "name":"test",
    "test_type":"document",
    "score_to_pass":32,
    "time_limit":324,
    "enabled":true,
    "online":true,
    "online_test_subject_id":1
    }
  }
```

The problem occurs when I try to use `jsonForm.Form' but the integers I've passed in like`time_limit`and`score_to_pass` are 0

```
{0 0 test 0 0  true true document    []}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have the expected property names (example: "ScoreToPass")

Comment: Your json tags start with Caps, your input json doesn't. Eg. `name` should be `Name` in your input json.

Comment: @DenysSéguret good catch, but after fixing that the error still persisted

Comment: Can you build a runnable demonstration of your problem on golang.org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

Needed to add `string` at the end of my json struc declaration, not sure why but it worked

```
type OnlineTestSet struct {
  ID                   int      `db:"id"                     json:"id"`
  OnlineTestSubjectId  int      `db:"online_test_subject_id" json:"online_test_subject_id,string"`
  Name                 string   `db:"name"                   json:"name"`
  ScoreToPass          int      `db:"score_to_pass"          json:"score_to_pass,string"`
  TimeLimit            int      `db:"time_limit"             json:"time_limit,string"`
  Description          string   `db:"description"            json:"description"`
  Enabled              bool     `db:"enabled"                json:"enabled"`
  Online               bool     `db:"online"                 json:"online"`
  TestType             string   `db:"test_type"              json:"test_type"`
  DocName              string   `db:"doc_name"               json:"doc_name"`
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you found it ! Good job, don't get discouraged because of the downvotes you received on your question.

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere: as you [can see](https://play.golang.org/p/jr1w4TPxba), if we artifically unmarshal the data you showed to us into your data types, it all works as expected.

Comment: @Elena The `string` in the json tag says that the json field will be passed as a string value but convert it to a int in the struct. Are you sure that you are passing the numeric values in json as numbers and not as string of number?

Comment: @Ankur, thank you for the explanation -  I changed it on the json end to be a string after loads of trial and error

Comment: @Elena Thank you for the answer! I invested/wasted more than a few hours on the same issue.